# Fullcalendar - Ajax not posting in IE8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, fullcalendar

Hi all I'm trying to write a php intranet for the company I work for but I have hit a brick wall with this problem:

IE8 users when they add an event by clicking on the day it asks all the questions fine, but then doesn't post anything in the MySQL Database but it does on later IE, FF and Chrome.

## Here's the Code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var user = '<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'][0]; ?>';
 var date = new Date();
 var d = date.getDate();
 var m = date.getMonth();
 var y = date.getFullYear();

 var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 editable: true,
 header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },

 events: "../../web_assets/calendar/events.php",
 data: 'user='+user ,
 type: "POST",

 // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
 eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
 if (event.allDay === 'true') {
   event.allDay = true;
 } else {
   event.allDay = false;
 }
 },
 selectable: true,
 selectHelper: true,


// Add event to Calendar
 select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
   if (title) {
   start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: '../../web_assets/calendar/add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title +'&owner='+ user +'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },
   // Update Event on Calendar (Move Item)
   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: '../../web_assets/calendar/update_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
    // Event update (resize event)
   eventResize: function(event) {
   start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: '../../web_assets/calendar/update_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 });
```

If someone can sort this out you'd make my day...

## Edit

I have made the changes you suggested, please could you tell me why the updating of events doesn't work?
I can post php PDO mysql statement if required...?

Comment: Internet Explorer is very sensitive to typos in JavaScript, while other browsers may ignore any small typos. So check your code carefully, it might be just a missing semi-colon or comma somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, first check the small typos, since IE8 is very sensitive to them.
Then:

1.You have duplicate declaration `editable: true,`

2.Here two variables are defined without `var` word:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
    start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and here again

```
eventResize: function(event) {
    start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

3.The data encoding is not safe this way

```
data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id,
```

better is (jQuery will serialize it for you):

```
data: {
    title: event.title,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    id: event.id
},
```

4.You can also add ajax error call-backs, like

```
$.ajax({
    /* removed the rest of the code for simplicity */
    success: function(json) {
        alert('Added Successfully');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('something went wrong');
    }
});
```

more info about ajax settings here (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Sorry, I can not help you any more without absolute back-end link.

Comment: Please could you help with why event update wouldn't be working above ^^^^

Comment: Well, to help you solving an issue, I should have the possibility to reproduce it. Unfortunately I can not do that without access to your back-end PHP server. What you can do yourself, is to follow my recommendations and clean-up your code. And then add error callbacks to your AJAX calls to get the idea of what is going on.